# Angular: Material Autocomplete is not working with post request?

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I am using Angular material autocomplete for my project but autocomplete is not working, I tried a lot to figure out where is the problem but currently I am out of options,

Showing **error** `response.filter is not a function` in a browser console only.
I am **fetching data with post request from node API where data is in JSON format**.

I am trying to show Title in search-box with autocomplete.

**JSON Data**:

```
 [{"Id": 1,
 "Title": "Pun",
 },
 {"Id": 2,
 "Title": "rocksold",
 },
 {"Id": 3,
 "Title": "Lehman",
 }]
```

**app.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppSetting } from './appsetting'
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'; 
import { tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppServiceService {
  private SERVERURL = AppSetting.API;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(user){
    console.log(user);
    return this.http.post<any>(this.SERVERURL+"users",user);
  }
 

  opts = [];

  getData() {
    return this.opts.length ?
      of(this.opts) :
      this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:3000/articles/publicationData',{}).pipe(tap(data => this.opts = data))
  }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef  } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AppServiceService } from './../app-service.service'; 
import { FormControl,FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { tap, startWith, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range } from 'rxjs';
 
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  myControl = new FormControl();
  options = [];
  filteredOptions: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,private auth : AppServiceService, private _router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder){
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(val => {
            return this.filter(val || '')
       })
    )

}
  
    ngOnInit() {}

    filter(val: string): Observable<any[]> {
      // call the service which makes the http-request 
      return this.auth.getData()
       .pipe(
         map(response => response.filter(option => {
           return option.Title.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0
         }))
       )
     } 

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
<input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
 <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.Title">
                        {{option.Title}}
</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: can you print the console.log(response) inside the map to check if you get the right data or not.

Comment: I feel you didnot get the right data maybe it is Object not an array that is why you get this exception  [filter in not a function ]

i see also your json file make sure that you wrapping the while data in [] to be as array

Comment: `map(response => response.filter(option => {return option.Title.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0 
console.log(response);
         }
         ))
       )` console.log is not working in map see

Comment: map( response => {
console.log(response);   
return response.filter(option => {return option.Title.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0 ;
})

Answer (score 0):

wrap your json data with [] to be

```
[
 {"Id": 1,"Title": "Pun"},
 {"Id": 2,"Title": "rocksold"},
 {"Id": 3, "Title": "Lehman"}
]
```

Comment: I think there must be issue in calling post API if you can check my API Call

Comment: do you have teamViewer ??  to check the code direct

Answer (score 0):

After checking the issue it was from response it self,  the response structure was like that

```
{
  results:[
   {item:1 ...},
   {item:2 ...},
   {item:2 ...},
 ]
}
```

which mean you have to change the map inside filter method to be

```js
filter(val: string): Observable<any[]> {
      // call the service which makes the http-request 
      return this.auth.getData()
       .pipe(
         map(response => response.results.filter(option => {
           return option.Title.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0
         }))
       )
     }
```